How to calculate values for current and voltage limiting resistors in variable power supply?
I have an assignment, where I have to calculate the values for a current limiting resistor (R3) and a voltage limiting resistor (R14) for a variable power supply. The input voltage to the circuit is 30 V DC and the output should be adjustable between 0-15 V and 0-2 A. How do I calculate the values for the resistors?


Limiting voltage ... Ulim*r15/(r14+r15)=Uz_1N750A.

Limiting current ... r3/(r3+r2)uz_D1=r42 ...

Current limit $I_{SC} = \frac{R_3 V_Z}{(R_2 + R_3) R_4} $ Where $V_Z$ is a 1N750A Zener voltage.

And the output voltage is $V_{OUT} =  V_Z * (1 + \frac{R_{14}}{R_{15}})$

NB: the voltages through the two Zeners are not "exactly" the same ...
